# General term to describe the anti-pattern where the same concept is described in different ways?

Tags: terminology, naming, coding-standards, anti-patterns, definition

Our codebase is old and very large. Over the years, many developers have worked on the code and frequently refered to the same concept inconsistently.

For example, we have a "number that uniquely identifies the study" or "Study ID". This is refered to as `studyNum`, `examId`, `Exam`, `StudyNo`, `StudyID`, the odd `StudyUID` or just `ID`...the full list of variations, including variations in capitalisation, is tediously long! This makes searching difficult and the software harder to modify.

Is there a general software engineering term for this inconsistency/term creepage and the maintenance challenges that result?

[PS: Along with normal development work, I'm applying "Clean Code" (aka Robert Martin) principles to slowly tidy these up!]

Comment: Yes; it's called "Not following a coding standard."

Comment: I would reject the characterisation of these synonyms as an "anti-pattern". It is not a pattern being followed at all, not even an evil one. It is a wholly natural degree of inconsistency and noise that creeps in whenever anybody is not expending prodigious amounts of effort to maintain total consistency.

Comment: I think it's more of a "code smell" than an anti-pattern. It's in [this list](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/) (sort of) under "Inconsistent names."

Comment: @Steve: Respectfully, it doesn't take a lot of effort to keep coding style consistent; the difficulties it prevents far outweigh the effort it requires.

Comment: Tend to agree with Robert. This is about developers taking the time to care. But if the product has, through lack of care, got itself into a bit of a mess, then Steve is right that fixing the mess becomes complicated and time-consuming. This is the famous "broken windows" analogy in software engineering: if you want the software to be maintainable, take the time to keep it clean.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not sure how to gauge the effort to be honest. Imagine (and I'm not saying this rhetorically) if our employers regulated which words were permissible for verbal and written communication in English - would we really be of the view that the effort of compliance was modest, or that the difficulties prevented were worth it? I think sometimes coding standards reflect an alignment of opinion that is already present, rather than really outweighing the problems that result when opinions don't happen to align.

Comment: @Steve: `I think sometimes coding standards reflect an alignment of opinion that is already present, rather than really outweighing the problems that result when opinions don't happen to align.` -- Quite right.  The "correct" coding standard to follow is the one the software shop is already using.  But there are norms; most C# shops follow the rules already captured in Visual Studio, for example.  English is already regulated; that's why we have grammar, punctuation and spelling rules.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, English is not regulated to the extent that there are no synonyms, or no disagreements about commas, and so on. As I say, if coders in a shop happen to agree for the time being then that's great, but actually imposing a standard against anybody's will, or establishing a standard when conflicting opinions actually exist, can have extreme costs indeed. Even "go with what exists" can as easily come up against "when in a hole stop digging", or come up against a experienced contractor who wants to go with industry standard rather than (an idiosyncratic) shop standard.

Comment: @Steve: It's not that weighty of a problem.  The best coding standards are one to three pages long; they define the basics, and leave room for judgement calls.  Ultimately, it's a "polite society" agreement; going against the grain of an already-established convention because you happen to like your own personal style is just rude and inconsiderate.  Nobody says "smth"  in their resume, if they expect to get a job.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree about coding standards being easy to maintain if they're used from the get go, but this is significanly harder in established spaghetti codebases. The problem is that any developer who actually follows the entire standard ends up going on a very long adventure, cleaning things as they go, and whatever task that brought them to this part of the application pales in comparison to the refactoring effort they did by upholding the standard. Instead, devs in spaghetti code make compromises, which mean an imperfect standard, and different devs make different compromises.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That is not to say that those compromises are good, but it's hard to sell a company on a boundless rewrite of source code without any promise of consistent feature development or bugfixing. So the more reasonable approach here is to deliver the features, and clean up as much as you can within reasonable limits - and this is exactly where things get fuzzy and the unified coding standard very easily goes astray with developers prioritizing what/how to clean things up differently.

Answer (score 0):

You already named it:  [***inconsistent naming***](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/1099.html).  That's a neutral observation, but it is known to [indirectly lead to quality issues](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5328661).

If `SudentID` was part of the specs, it's called a [***non-conformance***](https://www.qualityze.com/nonconformance-vs-noncompliance-brief-guide/).  That's a [quality issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality).

If `StudentId` or the name construction as `<Entity>ID` was part of a standard, it's called a [***non-compliance***](https://www.qualityze.com/nonconformance-vs-noncompliance-brief-guide/). Also a quality issue.

If there was no specs nor standard defined when the legacy code was initially written, and `StudentID` came later,  that's called ***arbitrary decision making disconnected from reality*** ;-)